# Generating random but unique numbers for reference ID

Tags: php, random

I want to generate unique numbers so that I can use them as reference numbers to handle my client requests.

I dont want the numbers to be repeated neither am i using any database to store the numbers.

I simply want to use a simple algorithm to generate random numbers.

I am using something like

`rand(10*45, 100*98)`

Is it possible to do something like that.
I know my requirement seems quite odd, but I just want to know if its possible.

Comment: I am not using any database, I just wanted it to be simple like the reference number would be mailed to the client and owner and they could communicate with the help of that reference number.
The idea of @njk is good enough and logical enough

Comment: Must it be decimal (i.e base 10)?

Comment: no it can be any number

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why not just preface your random number with a Unix timestamp? This will ensure uniqueness.

```
$random = time() . rand(10*45, 100*98);
```

Otherwise, you can store your numbers in a file. If you can, store them in a database.

Comment: As long as you don't generate 2 in the same second, anyway

Comment: @SamDufel Could also use `microtime`.

Comment: append another randomized string to better the uniqueness

Answer (score 4):

Why not use the function, php provides for that purpose:

[uniqid](http://php.net/manual/de/function.uniqid.php)

Example:

```
uniqid(rand(10*45), true)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you accept hexadecimal numbers, then:

```
function random_id($bytes) {
    $rand = mcrypt_create_iv($bytes, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
    return bin2hex($rand);
}
echo random_id(5); // Ex: a06e0e4e72
```

5 bytes (i.e. 40 bits) creates about 2^40 (about a trillion) possible unique values. It should be more than random enough to create many unique IDs.

Comment: as I have stated, I was looking for numbers only. But thanks anyway :)